# Swift 5 Map View calloutAccessoryControlTapped view open

Tags: mkmapview, mapview

I'm looking to open a details view when user clicks on the callout (calloutAccessoryControlTapped func). I'm setting the rightCalloutAccessoryView to a button that i hide and after, inside calloutAccessoryControlTapped i want to catch the event and open a view.

I have tried many solutions I found on internet using navigation controller but I couldn't make it work.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var objMapData = MapModel.objMapModel
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return MapView.Coordinator()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let view = objMapData.mapView
        
        view.showsUserLocation = true
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "AnnotationView")
            
            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotationView")
            }
            
            if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self){return nil}
            else {
                annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "map-pin-not-selected")?.resize(35, 35)
            }

            let leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pump_left_blue"))
            leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 75)
            leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftView
            
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView?.frame = CGRectZero

            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            
            return annotationView
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            view.image = UIImage(named: "map-pin-selected")?.resize(35, 35)
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            view.image = UIImage(named: "map-pin-not-selected")?.resize(35, 35)
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
            // open an existing view, LocationDetailedView
        }
    }
}

struct LocationDetailedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Location details")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("colGrayText"))
                        .font(
                            .system(
                                size: 14,
                                weight: .bold,
                                design: .default
                            )
                        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you added a working example to start with.